# UITableView is not deleting record from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

Here is my code to delete value. Table view is deleting record temporary when I restart my app it will  show deleted records also...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [bookmarks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];  [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: do you want to delete only particular value ? or full list ?

Comment: [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"] synchronize]; add this

Comment: /.m:130: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be In this line

Comment: then use it like this as said                            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
[prefs setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];    
[prefs synchronize];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// Your code    
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
[prefs setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];    
// saving it all  
[prefs synchronize];
```

Comment: It is deleting records, But when I am trying to add record it is not adding alwaysNSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"Bookmarks"] mutableCopy];
        if (!bookmarks) {
            bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [bookmarks addObject:[[[[self webBrowser]request] URL] absoluteString]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];
        [bookmarks release];

Comment: You are allocating memory to bookmarks in if(!bookmarks). What about the other condition. If you are releasing the array outside if(){}, the you need to allocate memory for it.

Comment: I Used your Answer code  for inserting user default, and it is working fine.thanks for help